# Getting blob type Doctrine entity property returns data only once

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I use Doctrine to store options/various bits of odd data in an array and serialise it to database where it gets stored as a blob. Everything was working fine until today I had to get that array twice and noticed that it gets the correct value only the first time. Any successive attempts return false, which is what unserialize/stream_get_contents returns on failure.

My best guess is that doctrine closes the stream after it fetches the data, but it doesn't make much sense. I need the data to be available throughout the request. I'm not an expert with streams so:

**How can I fetch blob data multiple times or prevent the stream from closing?**

Doctrine entity and it's methods:

```
/**
 * @var resource
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="options", type="blob")
 */
private $options;

/**
 * Set options
 *
 * @param array $options
 *
 * @return Campaign
 */
public function setOptions($options)
{
    $this->options = serialize($options);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get options
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getOptions()
{
    return unserialize(stream_get_contents($this->options));
}
```

Retrieve serialized options array:

```
$campaign   = $this->em->getRepository('TreasureForgeMessageBundle:Campaign')->find(1);
$options1   = $campaign->getOptions(); // Correct options array
$options2   = $campaign->getOptions(); // false
$options3   = $campaign->getOptions(); // false
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing occur because you do not [rewind()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rewind.php) your handle in between read operations.

However, unserializing the option array on each access is a bad idea considering performance. The `$options` string would have to be converted to an array on each access. Instead, you should tell doctrine that `$options` is an array, which will then be automatically serialized and unserialized only when data is read from and written to the database:

```
/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="options", type="array")
 */
private $options;

/**
 * Set options
 *
 * @param array $options
 *
 * @return Campaign
 */
public function setOptions($options)
{
    $this->options = $options;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get options
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getOptions()
{
    return $this->options;
}
```

**Update:**

Doctrine array types are described [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#array-types).

Comment: You're a genius! Adding `rewind($this->options);` just before `return unserialize(stream_get_contents($this->options));` fixed it. I was pulling my hair out!

Comment: Glad I could help. However, you should consider letting Doctrine do the array <-> blob conversion. :)

Comment: [Doctrine Array Type](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/types.html#array-types) Interesting, I didn't know Doctrine had an array data type. Thanks.