How to treat BLOB column as string in Doctrine?
Using Doctrine 3.1 - In my entity I have this column:
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'blob')]
    private $dataJpg;

If I make it string, PHP complains that resource is used and it cannot assign it during hydration. The problem is that I dont want to use resources at all, I want the binary data in its string form.
It is easy to work with resource when doing getter:
    public function getDataJpg(): ?string
    {
        $jpgData = $this->dataJpg;
        /** @var resource|null $jpgData*/
        if ($jpgData !== null) {
            return stream_get_contents($jpgData);
        }
        return null;
    }

But for setter I do not know how to approach it. I get string variable which I want to persist, but I cannot assign it to a resource. A workaround would be to fopen('php://memory') but I dont like that.
I need a way to tell doctrine to hydrate blob data as strings, so that I can get and set strings only and not care about resources.

You need to create your own type https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/3.2/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html and write your hydrate logic there.

For those interested, as suggested by @BERKUT in the comment, here is the custom type I made:
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\DBAL\Types;

use Doctrine\DBAL\ParameterType;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\ConversionException;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;


class BlobStringType extends Type
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $column, AbstractPlatform $platform): string
    {
        return $platform->getBlobTypeDeclarationSQL($column);
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return 'blob_string';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getBindingType(): int
    {
        return ParameterType::LARGE_OBJECT;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     **/
    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform): mixed
    {
        if ($value === null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (is_string($value)) {
            return $value;
        }

        if (! is_resource($value)) {
            throw ConversionException::conversionFailed($value, Types::BLOB);
        }

        $result = stream_get_contents($value);

        if ($result === false) {
            throw ConversionException::conversionFailed($value, Types::BLOB);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform): mixed
    {
        if (is_null($value)) {
            return null;
        }

        if (is_string($value)) {
            $value = $this->convertStringToResource($value);
        }

        return $value;
    }

    /**
     * @return resource
     */
    public function convertStringToResource(string $value)
    {
        $fp = fopen('php://temp', 'rb+');
        assert(is_resource($fp));
        fwrite($fp, $value);
        fseek($fp, 0);

        return $fp;
    }
}



Why invoking stream_get_contents() twice without rewind()? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303513/getting-blob-type-doctrine-entity-property-returns-data-only-once

I have edited the answer, but I still see no reason to use rewind

To re-invoke stream_get_contents($resource) without returning null.
